# how to generate new table from existing table by grouping them aggregated MODE values

Tags: python, pandas

I've a data frame in pandas, and I'm trying to generate a new table based on existing table by grouping them with their aggregated mode value.

```py
df
country scores  attempts
india    11 6
india    12 3
india    12 3
india    12 7
india    10 3
india    12 3
pakistan 10 4
Pakistan 14 4
pakistan 14 5
srilanka 23 5
srilanka 21 5
srilanka 21 6
srilanka 23 5
srilanka 23 6
srilanka 23 5
```

Result will be like this

```py
    country scores  attempts
0   India    12  3
1   Pakistan 14  4
2   srilanka 23  5

please help me solve this issue.
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: grouped=df['scores'].groupby(df['scores']) \n grouped.mean()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) first and then get first modes by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indice by maximal counts:

```
print (df)
     country  scores  attempts
0      india      11         6
1      india      12         3
2      india      12         3
3      india      12         7
4      india      10         3
5      india      12         3
6   pakistan      10         4
7   pakistan      14         4 
8   pakistan      14         4 <- correct data
9   srilanka      23         5
10  srilanka      21         5
11  srilanka      21         6
12  srilanka      23         5
13  srilanka      23         6
14  srilanka      23         5
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(['country','scores','attempts']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
    country  scores  attempts  count
0     india      10         3      1
1     india      11         6      1
2     india      12         3      3
3     india      12         7      1
4  pakistan      10         4      1
5  pakistan      14         4      2
6  srilanka      21         5      1
7  srilanka      21         6      1
8  srilanka      23         5      3
9  srilanka      23         6      1

df2 = df1.loc[df1.groupby('country')['count'].idxmax()].drop('count', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
    country  scores  attempts
0     india      12         3
1  pakistan      14         4
2  srilanka      23         5
```